# Help with a programming pattern in django that involves model forms

Tags: django, design-patterns, django-models, django-forms

My question is a bit long due to my lack of knowledge of good programming practices and, above all, Django. I appreciate any suggestions.

**The Model (simplified)**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    # Customer info
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=179, null=True, blank=True)
    # ... and more fields that need validation but not needed for the question
    pay_method          = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAY_METHODS)
    bank_code           = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_office_code    = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_control_digit  = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    bank_account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Subscription(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    product  = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    user     = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # ...
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date   = models.DateField(null=True)
    # ...
    is_main_subscription = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Subscription,null=True,blank=True)
    #...
```

**The problem**

There are two very similar subscription processes. One is for new users and the other for existing users.

For new users the subscription process involves filling Customer's personal data and payment info in the Customer table and creating at least one Subscription. Each Subscription refers to a Product. At the end of the process an Invoice for all those Subscriptions is generated. I think that the Invoice model is not necessary here but I put it here in case it is useful. Each Subscription has a django-contrib-auth User to log into the app.

The first Subscription is the *main subscription*. The User associated with that Subscription can renew or cancel the other subscriptions and buy new ones. That new process involves changing the payment info if needed, but no personal data for the Customer. And we must distinguish existing Subscriptions of the new ones.

**Forms**

For the Customer I've created three ModelForms:

PaymentForm is used alone for logged in users in the subscription process

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            'pay_method',
            'bank_code',
            'bank_office_code',
            'bank_control_digit',
            'bank_account_number'
        )
    # ...
```

DataForm is used alone for logged in users whose subscription is the main subscription to edit the Customer personal info out of the subscription process.

```
class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            # All the other fields
        )
    # ...
```

NewCustomerForm worked for me to create a form mixing PaymentForm and DataForm

```
class NewCustomerForm(MyDataForm, PaymentForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = MyDataForm.Meta.fields + PaymentForm.Meta.fields
```

For Subscriptions I think that there should be two FormSets (inline formsets?):

- RenewalsFormSet: For logged in users to cancel or renew existing subscriptions. User can't edit info, only cancel or renew.
- SubscriptionsFormSet: For logged and not logged in users, to add new subscriptions.

How could I handle both cases in the simplest way? The new subscriptions formset must not have knowledge of existing subscriptions.

**And the question is**

The subscription process from the point of view of Django views would be:

1. **GET form view:** Forms are presented to the user.
2. **POST forms:** Forms are validated. If error: go to point 1. If success: save POST data in the session.
3. **GET confirmation view:** Summary of products to be purchased.
4. **GET confirm payment:** Depending of the pay method selected the process here may vary.
5. **GET thankyou page**

What can I do to have a single subscription process for both logged and not logged in users?

I had thought about some kind of object like a black box that receives input and returns a customer (existing or not, depending on whether the user was already registered) with all subscriptions and users, all ready to be stored in database.

But I don't know how to do it.

(If you've read so far is that you must be very nice. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what prevents you to fit your "blackbox" modelling to your existing data model.

All you need to do is to vary your form-set rendering depending on whether the user is subscribed already or not. If you also write a save method on the form, that updates the calling the external gateway to update the db, the view would remain exactly the same.

Is there any specific place where you are getting struck?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My ignorance, mainly, is what prevents me doing that "blackbox". I don't know if there is a better pattern to do it or if I need two blackboxes better than one, each one with its own additional validation.

Comment: I finally used this pattern without knowledge but it worked very fine to simplify the payment process workflow in the app. So the answer is ok. ¡Thanks!